# How do i check if a Api response exists

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I keep getting a null pointer exception i want to see if the response exists and if so println it out.

```
if (responsePlace.result.opening_hours.weekday_text.isNotEmpty() ){
println("The response for place time " + responsePlace.result.opening_hours.weekday_text[0].toString())}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
    responsePlace.let
    {
      when(it.isSuccessful) {
         true -> println(""The response for place time " + it.result.opening_hours.weekday_text[0].toString()")
         false -> println("something went wrong!")
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the handy `isNullOrEmpty()` method in kotlin.

So your method will look like

```
if (!responsePlace.result.opening_hours.weekday_text.isNullOrEmpty()){
println("The response for place time " + responsePlace.result.opening_hours.weekday_text[0].toString())}
```

take care of the '!' negation at the start of the condition

Answer (score 0):

You must check which object is null or better to post log trace.
you may use Kotlin safe call which will prevent NPE.

```
if(responsePlace?.result?.opening_hours.weekday_text.isNullOrEmpty())
println("The response for place time " + responsePlace.result.opening_hours.weekday_text[0].toString())
```